# I have some error in MDCVRP Model using gurobi

Tags: python

I had a code for  multi-depot VRP(MDVRP) in gurobi
with the Model:
[image: Model]

but in result x_ijmk.i,j is not match the depot(m)
if there is someone who knows where is the mistake or can give me another code for MDCVRP!

[image: Result]

parameter information:init_M=depot、init_M=customer、q=capacity、init_km=vehicle in depot、init_gi=customer demand 、init_xyii =customer place、init_xym =depot place

```
import numpy as np
import timeit
from gurobipy import *
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

init_M, init_N, q = (3, 6, 25)
init_km = [3, 3, 2]
init_gi = [3, 9, 5, 6, 14, 9]
init_xyii = [(74, 29), (64, 26), (67, 80), (88, 15), (21, 65), (72, 42)]


init_xym = [(40, 65), (55, 25), (90, 55)]
init_xyi = [(74, 29), (64, 26), (67, 80), (88, 15), (21, 65), (72, 42)
    ,(40, 65), (55, 25), (90, 55)]

plt.scatter([x[0] for x in init_xyii],[x[1] for x in init_xyii])
plt.scatter([x[0] for x in init_xym],[x[1] for x in init_xym],marker='d')
for i in range(init_N):
    plt.text(init_xyii[i][0]-3,init_xyii[i][1]+2,str(i+1) + '(' + str(init_gi[i]) + ')')
for i in range(init_M):
    plt.text(init_xym[i][0]-1,init_xym[i][1]+2,chr(ord('A') + i))

def get_children(lt_N):
    n = len(lt_N)
    result = []
    for i in range(2 ** n): 
        combo = []
        for j in range(n): 
            if(i>>j)%2:
                combo.append(lt_N[j])
        result.append(combo)
    return result


N = [i for i in range(init_N)]
M = [m+init_N for m in range(init_M)]
N_M = [i for i in range(init_M + init_N)]
K_m = [[k for k in range(m)] for m in init_km]

N_children = get_children(N)

G = init_gi
A = [(i, j) for i in N_M for j in N_M]


D = {(i, j): np.hypot(init_xyi[i][0] - init_xyi[j][0],
                      init_xyi[i][1] - init_xyi[j][1]) for i, j in A}

X = [(i,j,m,k) for i in N_M for j in N_M for m in range(init_M) for k in K_m[m]]
with open('Results' + '.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=",")

    md = Model('MDVRP')
    x_ijmk = md.addVars(X, name='x_ijmk', vtype=GRB.BINARY)

   
    md.setObjective(sum(D[i, j] * x_ijmk[i, j, m, k]  
                        for i in N_M for j in N_M for m in range(init_M) for k in K_m[m]), GRB.MINIMIZE)

    for m in M:
        md.addConstr(sum(x_ijmk[m, j, m-init_N, k]

                   for j in N for k in K_m[m-init_N]) <= init_km[m-init_N])
    for m in M:
        for k in K_m[m-init_N]:
            md.addConstr(sum(x_ijmk[m, j, m-init_N, k] for j in N)== sum(x_ijmk[j, m, m-init_N, k] for j in N))    
            md.addConstr(sum(x_ijmk[m, j, m-init_N, k] for j in N) <= 1)    
            md.addConstr(sum(x_ijmk[j, m, m-init_N, k] for j in N) <= 1)
  
    for i in N:
        md.addConstr(sum(x_ijmk[i, j, m, k]
                         for j in N_M for m in range(init_M) for k in K_m[m] if i != j) == 1)

    for j in N:
        md.addConstr(sum(x_ijmk[i, j, m, k]
                         for i in N_M for m in range(init_M) for k in K_m[m] if i != j) == 1)
  
    for m in M:
        for k in K_m[m-init_N]:
            md.addConstr(sum(G[i] * sum(x_ijmk[i, j, m-init_N, k]
                                        for j in N_M) for i in N) <= q)
  
    for m in M:
        for k in K_m[m-init_N]:
            for j in M:
                x_ijmk[m,j,m-init_N,k].ub = 0
                x_ijmk[j,m,m-init_N,k].ub = 0

    for i in N_M:
        for j in N_M:
            if i==j:
                for m in M:
                    for k in K_m[m-init_N]:
                        x_ijmk[i,j,m-init_N,k].ub = 0
            else:
               
                md.addConstr(x_ijmk.sum(i,j,'*','*') + x_ijmk.sum(j,i,'*','*') <= 1)

    for i in N_M:
        for m in range(init_M):
            for k in K_m[m]:
                md.addConstr(x_ijmk.sum(i,'*',m,k) == x_ijmk.sum('*',i,m,k))


    for m in M:
        for k in K_m[m-init_N]:
            for lt_nn in N_children:
                if 1 < len(lt_nn) < init_N:
                    md.addConstr(sum(x_ijmk[i,j,m-init_N,k] for i in lt_nn for j in lt_nn if i != j) <= len(lt_nn) - 1)


    # md.addConstrs((sum(is_facility_open[m] for m in M) == 1 for i in N), name='open_facility_once')


    # md.setParam('MIPFocus',3)
    md.optimize()
    for v in md.getVars():
        if v.x > 0:
            print(v.varName, "=", v.x)


    for i in N_M:
        for j in N_M:
            for m in range(init_M):
                for k in K_m[m]:
                    if x_ijmk[i,j,m,k].x > 0.01:
                        plt.plot([init_xyi[i][0],init_xyi[j][0]],[init_xyi[i][1],init_xyi[j][1]])



    print(md.objVal)
plt.show()
```

Help me to fix the code